# Validation Form submit button returns 404 after second try because of not existing URL in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, post, get, controllers, formvalidation-plugin

I'm facing a problem with form validation in Spring - MVC. To begin with, I have this .jsp page where a submit form asking for username and password is asked.

### Enter your credentials to login please

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="user" action="user/doLogin">
    <form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div" />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>User Name :</td>
            <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
            <td><form:errors path="name" cssClass="error" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>User Password :</td>
            <td><form:password path="password" /></td>
            <td><form:errors path="password" cssClass="error" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

The controller behind this form is the LoginController.java

@Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/user")
    public class LoginController { 

    @RequestMapping(value = "/doLogin")
    public String doLogin(@Valid User user, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {


        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "user";
        } else {
            model.addAttribute("name", user.getName());

            return "Done";
        }


    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String displayUserForm(ModelMap model) {

        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "user";

    }


    }
```

In my model package, I have my User object where i make use of

```
org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Range;
```

for validations purposes.

The validation works perfect but the problem is that whenever I put wrong credentials in my form and get the corresponding message, the next time I submit my credentials I get a 404 error because of wrong URL after the second invocation of submit button and doLogin() function (user/user/doLogin). What should I do in order to make it work properly? Thanks in advance for any info ! :)

Answer (score 0):

use `modelAttribute="users"` instead of `commandName="user"`

also you are missing the value of second request, if value is not specified this method cant be called.

```
@RequestMapping(value="?" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String displayUserForm(ModelMap model) {

        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "user";

    }
```